# Gyroscope drift in IMU

Tags: noise, imu, drone

So, a brief foreword. I'm not sure if this question belongs here or in the DSP community, its closely related to both, but I have a feeling this will be more of interest here nonetheless, so I am going to post here.

I have an IMU which I am using to measure the inertial frame of a drone. I'm not using a Kalman filter in this case, this is part of a 5th semester project at university, and Kalman filters aren't mentioned until 7th. As a result of this I have already created a complimentary filter topology to use and tested with an arbitrary cutoff. This is to remove the gyroscopic drift.

I have a ca. 5 second period at a 1 kHz sample time over which to integrate my gyroscope data (raw angular velocity) to estimate the drift. However I have heard this change is nearly DC, and I know the trapezioidal method is going to be fairly sensitive to the white noise present in the signal. as a result, I get values in the range of 1x10³ for each integral, with the yaw being slightly higher, which correlates to the papers I have read.

Would I see any benefit in using a larger data set to reduce stochastic error, should I instead look at using Huen or Runge-Kutta methods, or should I just cut my losses and set an arbitrary cutoff frequency based on what I already have?

Comment: If you think Kalman is the way to go, not having been formally introduced to it should not put a stop to your efforts: The whole reason to do projects at university is to foster student's ability to do their own research and acquire the knowledge they need! Real engineering life doesn't only pose problems which you already had in class ;)

Comment: it hasn't ;) I was talking to someone on the masters the other day about it, I know a lot more about it than most on my course, but because of the way our exam system works, including chapters on it in our report opens us up to a whole load of hurt.... the fact our supervisor advised directly against it is a good indicator I think, and complimentary filters seem to work in this case

Comment: I am planning to go on to do a masters in that area too (signal processing), so if I wasnt doing further reading, I'd be worried. but at the same time, the other people in my group are going different directions, so they bring their own interests and expertise to the table/drone lab, so we all have to know eachothers field for the exam

Comment: In a quadcopter, roll and pitch gyros are really just for roll *damping*, you don't care much about drift - *absolute* orientation comes from accelerometers.  Yaw is where you can care, but what sort of performance are you getting compared to your goal?   Cheap toys with no external reference will hold heading for the order of minutes now, for something better than that you'd probably want to include a magnetometer.

Comment: thats exactly what I've done :) We're investigating its application in offshore though, so it needs a GPS as well to accommodate for magnetic anomalies and the EMC environment